# How to include two database connections?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have included 1 database connection in my PHP file. The file that connects to the database is called connect.php. This works successfully with no errors. When I try to include 2 database connections in my PHP file, this is when I encounter errors. It seems as though, I can only connect to one database at a time because only 1 of the databases are connected. Is there a way to include 2 database connections in 1 file?

This is what I have right now:

```
<?php

    require "connect.php";
    require "informational-connect.php";

?>
```

This is what's included in connect.php:

```
<?php
    $db= new mysqli("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "ARTICLES");

    if($db->connect_errno)
    {
        die("Error");
    }


?>
```

This is what's included in informational-connect.php:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "INFORMATION-DATA");

    if ($db->connect_errno)
    {
        echo die("Error");
    }
?>
```

I am using MySQLi.

Comment: Can you provide the snippet in the two files? Also. the SQL part from the current file.. Redact the credentials part, just wanted to be sure of the problem..

Comment: @SujeetSinha Just updated the question with the snippets

Comment: Are you using same connection variables in both files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have different connections you have to give the connection variables different names

Besides, you need only one database to deal with, and therefore only single connection

Answer (score 0):

The database selection is associated with the connection resource. So you can select it once for each connection.

If you don't call mysql_select_db at all,then all your queries will need to specify explicit database prefixes before all the tables, e.g. select * from db1.table ....

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli` is provide a functionality for connect multiple database at a time.

> But How one single variable in a file can hold two different
>   connections ?

You should use two different variables for each database connection.

`$Db1 = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$db_name1);` // connection 1

`$Db2 = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$db_name2);` // connection 2